# How does object pointer works in c++?

Tags: c++, oop

I was trying to understand how a objects are stored in memory (heap) and how reference variable works. I wrote a simple program to understand the concept. But Why I am getting dereferenced address i.e. `*(&cat)` but not the `&cat` when function `callBar()` returns the address?

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::string;
class Cat{
        public: string name;
};
Cat* callBar(Cat *cat){
        cat = new Cat();
        cout<<&cat<<"\n";
        cout<<*(&cat)<<"\n";
            
        return cat;
}
int main(void){
        Cat *c = new Cat();
        cout<<&c<<"\n";
        cout<<callBar(c)<<"\n";
        cout<<*(&c)<<"\n";
        return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
0x7ffd38985d70
0x7ffd38985d48
0x56368fbd22b0
0x56368fbd22b0
0x56368fbd1e70
```

I created the instance of the class in the main and printed its address. I passed this object to another function and then printed its address again, which gave me new reference. Atlast, I deferenced it.

It is still not clear to me why I am getting dereferenced address i.e. `*(&cat)` but not the `&cat` when function returns?

Comment: There are no object references in the code provided.  Maybe the question should be:  _How does object pointers work in c++?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is still not clear to me why I am getting dereferenced address i.e. *(&cat) but not the &cat when function returns?

Inside `callBar` the relevant bits are...

```
Cat* callBar(...unused argument...){
    cat = new Cat();
    cout << &cat << "\n";
    cout << *(&cat) << "\n";
    return cat;
}
```

You're not getting `&cat` back because your return statement is `return cat;` not `return &cat;`.

But - the rest of your question - why are you getting `*(&cat)`?  The `&` operator there takes the address of the `Cat* cat` local variable, then dereferences it with `*`: those operations cancel out, so `*(&cat) == cat`.

Comment: How does it returns unchanged? I mean I am creating a new object on the same reference variable cat.
       `cat = new Cat();`

And If it cancel out then the addresses should match?

Comment: @SauravJaiswal • You are creating a new object on the same `callBar` local parameter variable `cat`.  That has the effect of setting `cat` to a different value, not of changing the caller's `c` argument.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't even notice that line in the function - too sleepy! :-/   Point still stands though - after you assign that value to `cat`, `*(&cat)` is the same thing.